# SE All Sites Page: How is a question is selected?

Tags: discussion, questions, stack-exchange

I am just exploring the [SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites). When I click on one of them it shows statistics about questions/answers with *one question* with a ***link***. [For Stack Overflow, this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724907/unexpected-behavior-after-assignment-of-function-object-to-function-wrapper):

[image]

How is a question selected?

- Based on popular [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)
- [From Hot Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot)
- Based on upvotes a question receives
- Based on views
- How frequently question is changed

Comment: Note that the SO 'hot question' is now [Why can't I get the argument count of a template function at compile-time?](//stackoverflow.com/q/57737052), which is what I used in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is selected from the [hot network questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions); you can see this in the POST request made for each card you click on:

- URL: `https://stackexchange.com/sites/card-data`
- Method: POST
- Parameters:

  - `siteId`: `1`
  - `fetchTopUsers`: `true`
  - `fetchHotQuestion`: `true`
- Response content type: JSON, object with `hotQuestionHtml` and `topUsersHtml` keys.

E.g., with a little Python code we can fetch the HTML snippet and get the title:

```
>>> card = requests.post("https://stackexchange.com/sites/card-data", data={"siteId": 1, "fetchTopUsers": "true", "fetchHotQuestion": "true"}).json()
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> print(BeautifulSoup(card["hotQuestionHtml"]).a.string)
“Why can't I get the argument count of a template function at compile-time?”
```

This is the most recent hot network question for Stack Overflow.

You can verify this by [requesting the Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-for-mobile), filtering the JSON response (a list of objects) on the site name, and picking the most recent result as indicated by the `creation_date` field:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> data = requests.get("https://stackexchange.com/hot-questions-for-mobile").json()
>>> so = [d for d in data if d['site'] == 'stackoverflow.com']
>>> top = max(so, key=lambda d: d['creation_date'])
>>> print(top['title'])
Why can't I get the argument count of a template function at compile-time?
```

The HNQ list is limited to 100 questions so not every site is listed in it, but that limit is artificial. For example, Server Fault currently doesn't have a post in the HNQ listed but the one on the card probably would make the cut if the limit was raised; its [hotness score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions/61343#61343) just doesn't make the grade. In this case, the score is pretty low, so there are basically no 'better' candidates on Server Fault right now.